# importing url without module script type in javascript

Tags: javascript, import, handlebars.js

Is it **possible** to **Import** an **URL** without the module script type??

i was thinking, how **Vue** or **Angular** import the [Handlebars](https://handlebarsjs.com/)?

This is my **JavaScript File:**

```js
import "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/3.0.11/vue.cjs.js";
```

and This is my **HTML File:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7,8,edge" />
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Testing...</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Hello World!
    </body>
   <script src="index.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
</html>
```

**Result:** `Cannot use import statement outside a module`

**NOTE:**

> if you want to ask, *"why you need import? just use script tag"*. I'm actually trying to create a Framework.

*Sſ ɐɹᴉ∀ :sᴉ ǝɯɐu ʞɹoʍǝɯɐɹɟ ǝɥʇ 'M┴q*

Comment: cant you use index.js/wrapper parent js as type='module'?

Comment: absolutely no. it's a framework